# Electron application not launching

Tags: node.js, electron

I am new to Electron and was trying to create a simple application.  I dont want to install electron globally.  Rather, want it installed only in the application.  When I run npm run start, nothing happens.  Just eletron . gets displayed on the command line.  What is wrong with my code and anywhere where I can see the logs

My appstructure:
MusicPlayer

- app-> index.html
- node_modules
- main.js
- package.json

Package.json is:

```js
{
  "name": "musicplayer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "ABC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.6.11"
  }

}
```

Main.js is:

```js
const electron = require ('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
var mainWindow = null;

function createWindow()
{
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:612,height:384});
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirName}/app/index.html`);
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend using [electron-forge](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge) if you're new to electron or checking out [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start)

You should be using `url.format` for loadURL.

Try this:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

var mainWindow = null;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 612, height: 384 });
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

I copied your setup in this works

Comment: Doesn't seem to be helping.  May be something wrong with my installation.  I even installed electron globally.  Tried the electron-quick-start.  Even that hangs after displaying electron .    No window opens up.  Any ideas?  Just adding I am on WIndows 10

Comment: I guess try uninstalling all electron stuff and then install again

Comment: @user6223198 Also did you try [electron-forge](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge)?